# Is it possible to stop a jQuery Timeout function when a user leaves the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I set a timer into a view using the jQuery:

```
var timer, myDiv = $('#mydiv');
$(document).on('mousemove', function(ev) {
    var _self = $(ev.target);

    clearTimeout(timer);

    if (_self.attr('id') === 'mydiv' || _self.parents('#mydiv').length) {
        return;
    }    

    if(!myDiv.hasClass('show')) {
       myDiv.fadeIn();
    }          

    timer = setTimeout(function() { 
        myDiv.fadeOut(1000, function() {
            myDiv.removeClass('show');
        });
    }, 1960);    
});
```

I need to use this timer in one only single page for all the time a user still there.

Is it possible to use jQuery or JavaScript to stop the timer when a user leaves the page and goes through another view?

here a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ohyh3qsp/1/)

Comment: `myDiv.stop()` perhaps?

Comment: @AcidShout thanks for suggestion, but the timer should be enabled for all the time the user still inside the page

Comment: Neither `setTimeout` nor `clearTimeout` are jQuery things. They are vanilla-js things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `clearTimeout`:

```
clearTimeout(mytimer);
```

Comment: already tried but on Ajax I have problem, it seems not working

Comment: Ok, I update with more code, I tried to be synthetic :)

Comment: So you basicly want to pause the timeout as soon as the user leaves the page?

Comment: Yes, and I have no idea

Comment: I need to kill the timer when a user leaves the page not the tab or the website, but when he simply goes in another view

Comment: To elaborate on this, you can use jquery's .blur() function: `$(window).blur(function() {clearTimeout(mytimer);})`

Comment: You will also want to wrap your timer creation in a $(window).focus() event. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ohyh3qsp/2/